# How to avoid distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a query which works when I use DISTINCT. However I have a feeling I could rewrite the query in a way that would help me avoid use of DISTINCT, which would make easier(quicker) for the database to process the query.

If there is no point in rewriting the query, please explain, if there is, please look at simplified query and give me a hint how to reformulate it so I wouldn't get duplicates in the first place.

```
SELECT Us.user_id, COUNT( DISTINCT Or.order_id ) AS orders
FROM users AS Us
LEFT JOIN events AS Ev ON Ev.user_id = Us.user_id
LEFT JOIN orders AS Or ON Or.event_id = Ev.event_id
OR Or.user_id = Us.user_id
GROUP BY Us.user_id
```

Short description of the query: I have a table of users, of their events and orders. Sometimes orders have column user_id, but mostly it is null and they have to be connected via event table.

Edit:

These are results of the simplified query I wrote, first without distinct and then including distinct.

```
user_id orders
3952    263
3953    7
3954    2
3955    6
3956    1
3957    0
...

user_id orders
3952    79
3953    7
3954    2
3955    6
3956    1
3957    0
...
```

Problem fixed:

```
SELECT COALESCE( Or.user_id, Ev.user_id ) AS user, COUNT( Or.order_id ) AS orders
FROM orders AS Or
LEFT JOIN events AS Ev ON Ev.event_id = Or.event_id
GROUP BY COALESCE( Or.user_id, Ev.user_id )
```

Comment: which of these ids are unique, what are the relationships

Comment: At a guess, isn't `order_id` unique in the `orders` table?  In which case, `DISTINCT` serves no purpose here.

Comment: order_id is primary. however I've tried the query without it and it gives higher numbers.

Comment: Are there records in the order table with both a user_id and event_id? If so, the distinct is filtering them out - they will match both clauses in your join.

Comment: no there are no such records. but I get a lot of duplicates and at this point I am wondering why.

Comment: in that case, "distinct" is hiding a bug. I'd start by turning this into a union - one query to get records where the orders.user_id exists, the other to run the join over events. See iif that makes sense, then run the "count" over the union.

Comment: DISTINCT plus a double LEFT JOIN is suspect(are the two foreign keys nullable?) . Using 'Or' as a correlation name is also suspect.

Comment: Might an order be attached to more than one event?  Or a user to an event multiple times?  In such cases, `DISTINCT` will be necessary if you want to count the number of individual orders associated with a user as without it you'll count the same order against that user once for each time they're associated with it.

Comment: bad choice of an alias "OR" for "ORDERS" table... if anyone had to look at your code in the future and change or remove the OR thinking logical... not cool.

Comment: Oh, I have different alias in real query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting anything from the user table, nor the events table, so why join them.  Your last "OR" clause makes explicit reference that it has a user_ID column.  I would hope your order table has an index on the user ID placing the order, then you could just do

```
select
      user_id,
      count(*) as Orders
   from
      orders
   group by
      user_id
```

Comment: I actually do need the events table, but I've realized I could go without the user table and group by COALESCE( Ev.user_id, Or.user_id ), so I reorganized the query without using user table and that actually solved the problem. Thank you, I knew I was just messing somewhere and I could go without the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If an order can be associated with multiple events, or a user with an event multiple times, then it is possible for the same order to be associated with the same user multiple times.  In this scenario, using `DISTINCT` will count that order only once per user whereas omitting it will count that order once for each association with the user.

If you're after the former, then your existing query is your best option.